# Unable to write in VScode settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems i am unable to write in any new setting as my settings.json has an error of some kind. I have tried removing certain duplicate lines and also adding new brackets to see if it would assist with the issue but so far i have not been able to figure out the problem. Here is what i have managed to do so far,

```
{
  "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
  "editor.suggest.statusBar.visible": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": null,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum)",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "emmet.preferences": {
  
  },
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
  },
  "mssql.connections": [
    {
      "server": "{{put-server-name-here}}",
      "database": "{{put-database-name-here}}",
      "user": "{{put-username-here}}",
      "password": "{{put-password-here}}"
    }
  ],
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "editor.tabSize": 3,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true
  {
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
}
}
```

I get an error saying "expected comma Ln33 col 3" and "end of file expected at Ln 37"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from:

```
 "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true
  {
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
}
```

to

```
 "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,  // choose true/false/active
 // {                                 // gat rid of this {
 "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
// "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
// }                                 // get rid of this }
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! So seeing it now, I suppose i had some misplaced brackets as well as some unnecessary stuff.